# Headless browser automation app via electron js app

Tags: node.js, selenium, phantomjs, electron

I would like to create an electron app that can do some web automation based on user input into a GUI. In my research it seems my two best bets are Phantom and Selenium+Chromedriver.

The thing I'd like to do is have an app that someone else could download and run without any additional setup. It seems with Chromedriver and Phantom that I'd need to have others download and add these things to their PATH. In order to get things functioning.

Is there a way around this? Or is there another approach I should be taking? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should have a look at [Nightmare.js](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) which is like PhantomJS in many ways, but uses Electron under the hood (and that's good, because Chromium in Electron is very fresh compared to PhantomJS engine).

If you still want to use PhantomJS in Electron that's quite fine too. You may bundle it with your application or install npm module as a dependency and require that in your script. The main thing is - PhantomJS will be installed together with your app and you know the path to that folder.